# Copy of the screen area

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I need to move the black square in an arbitrary area of ​​the screen and copy screen area inside black square to area in my application.
How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I can copy a portion of the screen. But I can not move black square outside the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx

As for the movable black rectangle, I'd suggest making a transparent form and manually painting the border as desired.  Use the client area size and position of the form as a hint as what to pass to `CopyFromScreen()`.

Comment: So I have to make a form with a transparent background for the entire width of the screen?